# "Так" "такая" "такой" and "Какой"

Tags: грамматика, выражения

I've been watching these words recently and I am not quite sure how to use them. 
I know that Tak is like "so" or "that"(like in; *It's not that good*)

Could anybody please explain me?

Comment: [related](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/16092/when-to-use-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-or-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-respectively-for-emphasis)

Comment: a concise answer: такой/такая - with adjectives, так - with proverbs, какой - interrogative pronoun whose subject is quality denoted with an adjective, therefore the gist of the response should be the adjective